# fixing subversion commit with invalid comment

Tags: svn, git

I used git svn do commit into my svn repository and the comment contained an invalid character. When I try to change the comment as described [here](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg) I get the following error:

```
svn propedit -r 2958 --revprop svn:log https://svnhost/path/to/repository
svn: Valid UTF-8 data
(hex: 68 6d 65 6e 66 61 6b 74 6f 72 20 75 6e 64 20 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 70 72)
followed by invalid UTF-8 sequence
(hex: e4 6d 69 65)
```

Does anybody have a tip how to fix that commit without having administrator rights on the repository?

Comment: This depends on your locale and the handling of non-ASCII chars. I remember this being quite a pain some while ago, not sure we even got that fixed.

Comment: Have you tried both the propedit and propset variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the link you included to the `change-log-msg` FAQ and running the command you and they listed is precluded by the fact that the repository is configured to actually allow a log message to be modified.  By default the repository is not.  To enable the modification of log messages requires that the script `pre-revprop-change` be activated, and this can only be done by someone (usually an admin) with access to the file structure of the repository on disk.

It seems like you do not have the necessary access.  You can pass this along to the admin of the repository.  In this case simply renaming `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` to `pre-revprop-change` and making sure it is executable will enable modifying log messages:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

Thank you,
Zachary